# jQuery using .filter( ) for .addClass( )

Tags: jquery, filter, addclass

I am trying to use .filter() to .addClass() inputs and selects that are under .this-class Unfortunately my code below is not working.

Any ideas how this should work?

```
$('.this-class').filter('input', 'select').addClass('input-sm');
```

Comment: Should probably be `.filter('input, select')`

Comment: Alternatively, maybe `$('input.this-class, select.this-class')` so that it can be processed using the native browser methods?

Comment: Weird trying the answers do not work but using the code below works individually $('.this-class input').addClass('input-sm'); any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is what .filter is for...

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting wrong the items to filter.

Change:

```
$('.this-class').filter('input', 'select').addClass('input-sm');
```

to:

```
$('.this-class').filter('input, select').addClass('input-sm');
```

Answer (score 0):

look at the .filter() parameter

`$('.this-class').filter('input, select').addClass('input-sm');`